# Starcraft 2: Why use Roach over Hydra?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I have frequently hear casters talk about how Roaches have replaced Hydralisks in the mid game.  In what ways have roaches replaced hydras?  Isn't the DPS and range on a Hydra considerably better?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While it is true that the range 5 (or 6 after upgrading) is better than the roaches' range of 4, and that the DPS is considerably better (~14.5 vs 8 DPS), the roaches still have a number of advantages over hydras.

- Better Health: 145 vs 80
- Better Base Armor: 1 vs 0
- Better Speed post-upgrade: 3.0 vs 2.25
- Lower Cost: 75M 25G vs 100M 50G
- Faster Build Time: 27 seconds vs 33 seconds
- After upgrades, can move while burrowed.

Comment: +1 Here I was, wasting time looking up the stats you just listed: you win!

Comment: ..and they can heal fast while burrowed.

Comment: overall, the only disadvantage is the unability of shooting air, except if you're good at aiming with ravagers

Answer (score 6):

Probably because Roaches:

- are cheaper;
- don't require a Lair, so you get access to them earlier;
- can move while burrowed (requires Burrow);
- heal themselves while burrowed (if upgraded);
- run faster while not on creep (if upgraded).